# RASA nlu parse not give currect intent, give same intent in result

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, spacy, rasa-nlu

- RASA version : 0.10.5
- spaCy version :  1.9.0
- Installed models : en, en_core_web_sm

I am creating training data using dialogflow export data and successfully finished training but when I request and give some text it gives wrong intent result. It always gives the same intent in result and also every time same intent_ranking.

Please let me know how can I get proper intent results as well as entities result.

Comment: Try to convert all the entities json files which dialogflow creates by writing a python script or a C# method into [RASA training format](http://nlu.rasa.ai/dataformat.html) as detailed here. Then pass it to RASA to train. And remember the more utterances in the common_examples array, the more better your confidence score will be.

Comment: Also try using the NLP Mitie as a backend, for custom entities mitie is great compared to sPacy.

Comment: Thank you @KunalMukherjee, I am just starting to learning it I am created successfully training_data.json file using this command " python -m rasa_nlu.train -c config_spacy.json"  and then I run server "python -m rasa_nlu.server -c config_spacy.json" and pass text that time its given wrong intent

Comment: Have you tried to convert your DialogFlow json files into RASA format JSON files?

Comment: With reference of RASA doc "https://nlu.rasa.ai/migrating.html" I just put Dialogflow exports intents file in data/examples/dialogflow folder and train data and generated training_data.json file with same intent and text like in Dialogflow @KunalMukherjee

Comment: I also faced the same issue, I had converted all the DialogFlow json files into RASA format json and that fixed it.

Comment: DialogFlow json file and RASA format json Mapping perfect but when run server and pass text that time it give me wrong intent. Mitie give current Intent in result but it take long time to generate training_data.json file to train data @KunalMukherjee

Comment: Then the only way is to create a pull request in [RASA NLU Git Official](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu) stating your concern and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recommendation when Rasa NLU seems to be functioning correctly, but incorrectly classifying intents and entities is, **add more training data**.

So try that, but also try these other suggestions:

- Rasa recently released the [tensorflow embeddings pipeline](https://medium.com/rasa-blog/supervised-word-vectors-from-scratch-in-rasa-nlu-6daf794efcd8). This pipeline creates a small language model with the training data set and word vectors. It can, in general, can operate on a more modest data set. Set your pipeline in config.yml to `"tensorflow_embedding"` to give it a try.
- Use the [evaluate](http://nlu.rasa.com/master/evaluation.html#evaluation) script to see where your training data is the weakest. The script will generate f1 scores and a chart for showing which intents are being misclassified the most.
- Increase the size of your spaCy model. Without information on the language you are using or the spacy model you have installed, this is just a shot in the dark, but especially if you have installed the small spacy model for English (en_core_web_sm), you should try the medium or large size models which include word vectors.

With all that said, my experience with Dialogflow and Rasa NLU both suggest more training data is required for Rasa's implementation. Also if you continue to have problems join us on the [Rasa NLU Gitter](https://gitter.im/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu) and we can help you there.

Comment: How many is "more training data", 5 examples/intent,10 examples/intent,30 examples/intent, 50 examples/intent?

Comment: There isn't a set value, If you're intents are very similar you will need more data, if they are very different you will need less. Use the evaluate script to find weak performing intents and add more examples to those. Iterate on that until you are getting good results.

Comment: Also might be worth running your training data through Qbox to see where the confusion lies. From expeirience, simply adding more training data won't always work as there are usually only so many ways to phrase an intent. 
It's not like image classification where you can add 100 more cat images :)